# Build an ActiveRecord query based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following query which works just fine:

```
temp = Apartment
  .where(rooms: roomsArray)
  .where(area: areasArray)
  .where(price_interval: price_intervalsArray)
  .group(:rooms)
  .count
```

Now I'd like to only apply the .where-queries if some condition is fulfilled for each of them. So if roomsArray is empty, we skip the entire `.where(rooms: roomsArray)`-query. And the same for areasArray and price_intervalsArray.

How can I build the query with conditions?

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
temp = Apartment
unless roomsArray.empty?
    .where(rooms: key) 
end
unless areasArray.empty?
    .where(area: areasArray)
end
unless price_intervalsArray.empty?
    .where(price_interval: price_intervalsArray)
end
.group(:rooms)
.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of this format. I personally like this way.

You can set the keys in hash conditionally and pass the hash to `where`.

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:rooms] = roomsArray if roomsArray.present?
conditions[:area] = areasArray if areasArray.present?
conditions[:price_interval] = price_intervalsArray if price_intervalsArray.present?
Apartment.where(conditions).group(:rooms).count
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain them correctly

```
temp = Apartment.all

if roomsArray.any?
  temp = temp.where(rooms: key) 
end

# or like this with shorter syntax
temp = temp.where(rooms: key) if roomsArray.any?

# and so on with the other conditions
# and then temp will include what you want...

temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = Apartment.all
temp.where!(rooms: roomsArray) if roomsArray.present?
temp.where!(area: areasArray) if areasArray.present?
temp.where!(price_interval: price_intervalsArray) if price_intervalsArray.present?
temp.group(:rooms).count
```

P.S. `present?` returns `false` if the receiver is `nil` or is empty. `where!` modifies the relation (the wrapper of query) in place.